# How to run sample application in WSO2 ESB?

Tags: java, wso2-esb

We are working on WSO2 ESB, facing some issues while executing the sample **SimpleStockQuoteService**. As per our understanding the client is sending request to WSO2 server and server is interacting with back end service to get the response. We are sending request but not getting any response. Is there any order to execute the sample(i.e). start the servers in different command prompts.

Comment: Can you post your service?

Answer (score 0):

There is no any standard order to start the servers.

But first go to ***CARBON_HOME/samples/axis2Server/src/SecureStockQuoteService*** and build the service (with ant). Then only the SecureStockQuoteService will be deployed in the axis2 server.

Then start the axis2 server at ***CARBON_HOME/samples/axis2Server*** executing the ***./axis2Server.sh***. Then you can send the request and get the corresponding response.

Follow [1] for more details

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Setting+Up+the+ESB+Samples